# Nginx Routing for Subdomain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

We have a website that is running using nginx:

```
mywebsite.com.au
```

and let's say it's IP is `192.168.1.1`

Then we have an account in `https://cp.dnsmadeeasy.com/` we are using this to manage all our dns routing.  We have a portal which is located in

```
mywebsite.com.au/portal
```

So bascially the portal is just a directory inside `mywebsite.com.au`.

What we want to do is add a subdomain `portal.mywebsite.com.au`. We need a portal subdomain so we added an entry to dnsmadeeasy.

What we want is when you browse `portal.mywebsite.com.au` is we can see the same thing in `mywebsite.com.au/portal` so it's like a mirror of our portal. So we added the `portal` subdomain and also point it to same IP Address `192.168.1.1`. So technically it is pointed in the same server.

When I browse the site, `portal.mywebsite.com.au` it says nginx 403 forbidden.

My question is that, is `mywebsite.com.au` and `portal.mywebsite.com.au` is being served in the same nginx installation or config? How do I map in nginx  `portal.mywebsite.com.au` to render the same content or files that is located in `mywebsite.com.au/portal`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `server_name` for [portal.mywebsite.com.au](http://portal.mywebsite.com.au) with it's root folder. So let's say your [mywebiste.com.au](http://mywebiste.com.au) root folder is `/var/www/html/` then your server configuration for [portal.mywebsite.com.au](http://portal.mywebsite.com.au) should look something like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name portal.mywebsite.com.au;
        root /var/www/html/portal;

        ...
}
```